# Mass of each alloy when the total mass is given

Tags: systems-of-equations, percentages

I'm struggling with the following problem.

**Problem**

There are $3$ alloys of nickel and zinc, their total mass is $30$ kg. The first alloy contains $40\%$ of nickel, the second one - $22\%$ of nickel, the third one - $90\%$ of nickel.

If we melt the first and the second alloys together, the resulting alloy will contain $30\%$ of nickel, and if we melt the first and the third alloys together, the resulting alloy will contain $30\%$ of zinc.

Find the mass of each of the three alloys.

**Solution** (well, sort of)

So far I've done the following:

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3$ be the mass of nickel in each alloy,

let $b_1, b_2, b_3$ be the mass of zinc in each alloy.

Then we have:

$\dfrac{a_{1}}{a_{1}+b_{1}}=0.4\Leftrightarrow a_{1}=0.4\left(a_{1}+b_{1}\right)\Leftrightarrow0.6a_{1}=0.4b_{1}\Leftrightarrow3a_{1}=2b_{1}$

$\dfrac{a_{2}}{a_{2}+b_{2}}=0.22\Leftrightarrow a_{2}=0.22\left(a_{2}+b_{2}\right)\Leftrightarrow0.78a_{2}=0.22b_{2}\Leftrightarrow39a_{2}=11b_{2}$

$\dfrac{a_{3}}{a_{3}+b_{3}}=0.9\Leftrightarrow a_{3}=0.9\left(a_{3}+b_{3}\right)\Leftrightarrow0.1a_{3}=0.9b_{3}\Leftrightarrow a_{3}=9b_{3}$

$\dfrac{a_{1}+a_{2}}{a_{1}+b_{1}+a_{2}+b_{2}}=0.3\Leftrightarrow a_{1}+a_{2}=0.3\left(a_{1}+b_{1}+a_{2}+b_{2}\right)=0.7\left(a_{1}+a_{2}\right)=0.3\left(b_{1}+b_{2}\right)$

$\dfrac{b_{1}+b_{3}}{a_{1}+b_{1}+a_{3}+b_{3}}=0.3\Leftrightarrow b_{1}+b_{3}=0.3\left(a_{1}+b_{1}+a_{3}+b_{3}\right)=0.7\left(b_{1}+b_{3}\right)=0.3\left(a_{1}+a_{3}\right)$

Honesty, I don't know whether I'm on the right track and if yes, where I go further from here. I'd like to ask for help. I appreciate any recommendation.

Comment: Might make it easier to just use the numbers given to you instead of adding six more variables for masses of nickel and zinc.

Comment: @MicahWindsor Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by using numbers instead of variables. So far all the problems on alloys or salt solutions or something like that have required systems of equations.

Comment: "The first alloy contains 40% of nickel, the second one - 22% of nickel, the third one - 90% of nickel." You don't have to use $a_1,b_3,...$ because you are given those quantities. You don't want a system in nineteen variables if you can have it in three.

Comment: @MicahWindsor but I'm using variables for absolute values of their masses, not percentage. I don't know the masses, that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah, but why can't you just let $m_1,m_2,m_3$ be the masses you are trying to find (obviously you need to find the values of three variables), then define $n,z$ in terms of  $m_1,m_2,m_3$ where $n$ represents one percent composition of nickel and $z$ represents the same for zinc.

Comment: For example, $m_1=40n+(100-40)z$.

Comment: @MicahWindsor got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that life is simpler here:
$
\begin{cases}
x+y+z=30\\
0.4x+0.22y=0.3\left(x+y\right)\\
0.4x+0.9z=0.7(x+z)
\end{cases}\
\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
x=8\\
y=10\\
z=12
\end{cases}
$